# Convert Ember Model Attribute to String

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a template where I am trying to set the input value of an html form to a `model.name` value. However, I don't want changes in this box to affect the global store. Can I convert `model.name` to be string *only*?

Comment: Like this? [Ember.js documentation - One-Way Bindings](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/object-model/bindings/#toc_one-way-bindings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unbound` helper:

```
{{input value=(unbound model.name)}}
```